# MYSQL Merging 2 results into 1 table

Tags: mysql

Im building a c# program and am currently stuck at fetching data from MYSQL database and bind them to a grid view. I had been researching for a few days now but to no avail.

I have 4 table in the database.

```
table 1 - alpha
table 2 - bravo
table 3 - charlie
table 4 - delta

attributes of alpha (id, type, user, role )
attributes of bravo (id, type, date, user)
attributes of charlie (id,type, cat, doneby, comment)
atttibutes of delta (id,type,  cat, doneby)
* the pk of alpha and bravo is (id)
* the pk of charlie and delta is (id, type)
```

i did a query1 before by inner joinning alpha, bravo and charlie which leads to the sucessful result of

```
(id, type, date, user, role, cat, doneby, comment)
```

and

i also did a query2 before by inner joinning alpha, bravo and delta which leads to the sucessful result of

```
(id, type, date, user, role, cat, doneby)
```

Right now, im trying to built a query3 which will merge the result from query1 and query2 together.

the result of my attempts leads to 
(id, type, date, user, role, cat, doneby, comment,id, type, date, user, role, cat, doneby)

As i do not want the repeated columns, I would like to seek advice on how to get the result to become like the one below by placing the records as a new tuple in the result table.

```
(id, type, date, user, role, cat, doneby, comment)
```

Thanks!

P.S: the PK would not pose a problem due to (id, type)

Comment: If you don't want repeated columns, leave them out of your `SELECT` list.

Comment: The final results you want look the same as the results of query1. How does query2 fit into it?

Comment: But i need the results from the second query to be display in the data. However, due to the fact that the the second query does not contain "comment" in its scheme, hence I cant union it with query 1. As such, my progress only allow me to select all the attributes I required and display via repeated column, which is not what i wanted. I want the results from second query to merge with query 1 and appear as a new tuple in the result set. Thanks.

Comment: Merge in what way? They both have `doneby` columns, but they're coming from different tables. Which one should be used? You can use `UNION` by putting `NULL AS comment` at the end of query2's `SELECT` list (see Lajos Arpad's answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have separate tuples, in fact `union`-ing the two sets, then do the following:

```
(select id, type, date, user, role, cat, doneby, '' as comment from yourtable1)
union
(select id, type, date, user, role, cat, doneby, comment from yourtable2)
```

Read more about `union` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

Comment: Thank you very very much. Your solution works for me!

I tried union previously but due to the "Comment" column is not the same as query 1, hence i could not get it to work due to schema constraint.

Comment: Yes, I was sure this was the problem, I am glad I could help. Note that you can accept my post as the correct answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah, accepted it already. Thanks for you help! Have a great day ahead! =)

Answer (score 0):

Based in your last comment you could use the `UNION` then as **Lajos** already posted, like:

```
Query 1
UNION
Query 2
```

And for missing columns or column that could be found in either query you have to fill it with an empty one with the same column name.

See example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: Hi edper, I tried your solution and it does show the results. However, there are repeated tuple in the result (it shows type data from query 1 only) and the type data from query 2 does not show.

P.S : the data in the 'type' column differs from both query.
eg: query 1 'type' column holds only (a,b,c,d) while query 2 'type' column holds only (e,f,g,h). However, the id will be the same. 

Thanks.